# Does anyone know of a computer programming work patterns site?

Tags: debugging, design-patterns

There are all those Design Patterns wikis -- you know, with Singleton, Iterator and all that. I'm not looking for that. I'm looking for one level up from that: computer programming working patterns. Such as "Debugging", "RetreatAndSolveSmallerProblemFirst", and the like.

EDIT: Clarifying that I'm interested in individual work patterns rather than team ones. Think PSP rather than Agile.

If there isn't any such site, then maybe I'll start one. But no point reinventing the wheel (oops -- that would be ReinventingTheWheel) if there already is one.

The winning answer will be one that is either an URL of a site that you think meets the description, or a reasonably confident answer that there is no such site out there yet.

Extra no-points for URL being a wiki, for reminding me how to open my own wiki (is there something better than just a Wikipedia *page*?).

p.s. I don't really *like* CamelCase but if that's what's used on the site I'm looking for, then I'll manage.

Comment: +1 before the programming police close down the speakeasy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place I'd look for such patterns is the [C2 Wiki](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki), this is where I'd expect to find something about this (maybe in [OrganizationalPatterns](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OrganizationalPatterns) or [AmeliorationPattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AmeliorationPattern)). Actually, I start to find it hard to find anything on C2 which is sad because this wiki is really a gold mine.

Comment: Yes, this does seem to be the established place. Indeed hard to find anything. I did find http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CorrectiveAction which is close but focuses on team behaviors rather than individual behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

There's a book of patterns on organising software development teams, which has pattern names like "Architect controls product", "Subclass per team", "Code ownership", "Form follows function", "Build prototypes", "Named stable bases", "Don't interrupt an interrupt", "Developing in pairs", and 100 others: [Organizational Patterns of Agile Software Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131467409).

Comment: Agile Agile Agile Team Team Team. I will clarify my question.

Answer (score -1):

[Source Making](http://sourcemaking.com) maintains a listing of many common anti-patterns (kinda the exact inverse of what you want) as well as refactoring patterns and design patterns.

Comment: Indeed inverse of what I want. Nice text layout but not so useful to me.

Comment: Ok, I just thought that it would be helpful to identify "what to avoid" instead of "what to do"